# unable to access network admin of a blog

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I am unable to see it network admin link in a multisite blog. Can anyone tell me how to activate it again? I am logged in as super user. For the main blog I could see, I used to see the network admin link previously for any other blogs too if am logged in as super user but now I am unable to see. check the below images,

Before, I can see network for all sites if am logged in as super user

[image]

Now, I cannot see network admin link for any blogs

[image]

Comment: What has changed - any plugin updates, WP Core updates, etc. ?

Comment: I tried to network activate a plugin, but after this I deactivated and even tried deleting it. Still cant access.

Comment: When I try to access the url like 'http://blogurl/wp-admin/network' I get "Error establishing a database connection" though I could access 'http://blogurl/wp-admin/'

Comment: It sounds like the plugin tried to alter something in the database, and failed. Make sure your `wp-config.php` multisite settings are still in tact, and so is your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Or that it removed you as a super administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the username of the super admin was changed and this did not reflect in other blogs of the system. The below query solved my problem,

```
update wp_sitemeta set `meta_value` = 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"adminusername";}' where `meta_key` = 'site_admins'
```

and

```
update wp_sitemeta set `meta_value` = 'adminmail@adasd.com' where `meta_key` = 'admin_email'
```